# Plot date against time. Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, jitter

I have those crime data from San Fransisco. My original data looks like this. [san Fransisco data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16lfo.png)

Long story short, I need to plot dates against time(after performing some filtering) and create a jitter plot. The original format of the date and time column is object. Thats what is what I have done so far.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) 
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
x7=dfdrug.Date.tolist()
y7=dfdrug.Time.tolist()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hyld.png)

This is the best I could get, but still I am annoyed by that 7 next to the times. 
Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have converted the Time column to a `pd.datetime` object as well. The 7 you are seeing is a part of the date (truncated to only show the last part).

If you change your y values to Time objects you will likely get what you are after. E.g:

`y7 = df.Time.dt.time.tolist()`

Comment: I am afraid when i try to do this I get this error:  tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'str'

Comment: @Giorgio Sorry, this should be on the dataframe where you have converted it to a datetime. Updating answer now.